# lambda function and filtering in python

Tags: python, lambda

I am very confused with lambda function.

I have a host list and need 2 filtering ways lt and gt.

here is my host list
[a1.xxx.com, a2.xxx.com, a90.xxx.com, a100.xxx.com]

I need to use lambda function to filter out these hosts based on the host number (a"x"). So `gt:10` should give me `[99, 100]`. I need only the host numbers.

So first I need to extract the numbers from each host and apply > or <.

I am able to achieve this using list comprehensions but the code is duplicated between lt and gt functions.  I would like to have less code duplication, the only variable between lt and gt is the operator and everything else is common. Is there a way I can pass the lt,gt operator and avoid code duplication using lambda function?

current code using list comprehensions

```
def gt(number) :
    host_list = [x.split('.')[0].split('a')[1] for x in hosts if  int(x.split('.')[0].split('a')[1]) > int(number)]
    return host_list
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is running?

Comment: You need to show us the actual code.

Comment: Please could paste a snippet of your code ?

Comment: You can look at the magic methods `__lt__` and `__gt__` but doing it like this is quite ugly.

Comment: You could create a class Host that takes a string parameter and parses out the parts of the host address; then you could define what > and < mean for your class. Perhaps this would be overkill, however.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a scenario where filter and anonymous functions would be preferable to the corresponding comprehension. The comprehension can have a function as a parameter.

Comment: posted a working snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing that differs between your list comprehensions is comparison operator, then place the list comprehension inside a function and pass *operator function* to it as an argument. You can define operator functions yourself, but there's a [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module in Python's standard library which is more convenient in this case.

```
import operator

hosts = ['a1.xxx.com', 'a2.xxx.com', 'a90.xxx.com', 'a100.xxx.com']

def filter_hosts(hosts, number, op=operator.gt):
    return [host for host in hosts
            if op(int(host.split('.', 1)[0][1:]), number)]

print(filter_hosts(hosts, 10))
print(filter_hosts(hosts, 10, op=operator.lt))
```